# Customer Log In URL

Tags: url, login, toplinks

I realized that my login URL is very weird, with a lot of letters and numbers (like an encrypted text).

When I go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml` and check the item `<customer_logged_out>`, the reference for top.links looks fine: `customer/getLoginUrl`

But in my website the URL is something like:
https://example.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5iZWx(...)/

My question is: Is that correct?

I am having some CSS problems (classes based on top links) and when I navigate to https://example.com/customer/account/login/ everything works fine and looks like I should use this login screen instead of the first link.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The login URL is ok.

The letters and numbers are actually a base 64 decoded URL of the site your customer was before the login. They will be redirected to this page.

You can just do a `base64_decode` on this base64 decoded string to see what the content is if you're interested.